# Post installation script for ucsf-chimerax-daily returns Python errors

Tags: apt, dpkg, python3, pip

The problem occurred after I installed a poorly prepared install file for ucsf-chimerax, which resulted in the following error:

```
Install desktop menu and associated mime types
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "/usr/lib/ucsf-chimerax-daily/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in
_run_module_as_main  
    "__main__", mod_spec)  
  File "/usr/lib/ucsf-chimerax-daily/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in
_run_code  
    exec(code, run_globals)  
  File "/usr/lib/ucsf-chimerax-daily/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/ChimeraX_main.py", line 802, in <module>  
    exit_code = init(sys.argv)  
  File "/usr/lib/ucsf-chimerax-daily/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/ChimeraX_main.py", line 601, in init  
    run(sess, cmd)  
  File "/usr/lib/ucsf-chimerax-daily/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/chimerax/core/commands/run.py", line 31, in run  
    results = command.run(text, log=log)  
  File "/usr/lib/ucsf-chimerax-daily/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/chimerax/core/commands/cli.py", line 2561, in run  
    result = ci.function(session, **kw_args)  
  File "/usr/lib/ucsf-chimerax-daily/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/chimerax/core/commands/linux.py", line 19, in install  
    install(session, system=system)  
  File "/usr/lib/ucsf-chimerax-daily/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/chimerax/core/_xdg.py", line 421, in install  
    info = get_info(session, system)  
  File "/usr/lib/ucsf-chimerax-daily/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/chimerax/core/_xdg.py", line 474, in get_info  
    dists = pip.get_installed_distributions(local_only=True)  
AttributeError: module 'pip' has no attribute 'get_installed_distributions'
```

```
dpkg: error processing package ucsf-chimerax-daily (--configure):
installed ucsf-chimerax-daily package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
ucsf-chimerax-daily
```

The program runs well and I don't have problems with it in the menu. Only the message is irksome.
Every time I'm installing a new piece of software or upgrading packages, the error returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited the file `/var/lib/dpkg/info/ucsf-chimerax-daily.postinst`, commenting out the commands that did something else then echoing a message.

Then I simply ran

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

Some messages like

```
W: APT had planned for dpkg to do more than it reported back (0 vs 4).
   Affected packages: ucsf-chimerax-daily:amd64
```

but problem solved.
I think

```
sudo dpkg --configure ucsf-chimerax-daily:amd64
```

would also do the job.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the UCSF ChimeraX distribution.  Please report bugs with UCSF ChimeraX to chimerax-bugs@cgl.ucsf.edu so they can be fixed for all users.  Luckily, we saw this, so it has been fixed.  Please try the next daily release (2018-10-17).

Comment: sent link with this post question and its content